# How do I edit the following code to create the attached table in Overleaf?

Tags: latex

I replicated a paper to create the tables provided in it. I was able to export the tables from Stata to .txt files but I cannot seem to get them to run on Overleaf. Please let me know if I am missing certain commands in the code which are stopping me from recreating the attached table. Thank you.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}

Table 7: Social effects, Endline 1
    girl515_school_1    boy515_school_1 girl515_workhrs_pc_1    boy515_workhrs_pc_1 girl1620_school_1   boy1620_school_1    women_emp_index_1   female_biz_new_1    social_index_1
    b/se    b/se    b/se    b/se    b/se    b/se    b/se    b/se    b/se
treatment   -0.0158 -0.0117 -0.0281 0.613   -0.0374 -0.00708    0.00687 0.0143***   -0.00783
    ="(0.0130)" ="(0.0105)" ="(0.202)"  ="(0.743)"  ="(0.0242)" ="(0.0277)" ="(0.0231)" ="(0.00533)"    ="(0.00970)"
r2  0.00275 0.00515 0.00558 0.00288 0.0237  0.0223  0.00327 0.00341 0.00656
mn1 0.919   0.918   0.594   0.577   0.338   0.429   -0.00133    0.0259  1.24e-08
sd1 0.259   0.260   5.159   27.46   0.455   0.478   0.456   0.174   0.287
N   3035    3073    3035    3073    2174    1866    6862    6762    6862
pval    0.226   0.268   0.890   0.412   0.126   0.799   0.767   0.00825 0.421
Robust standard errors, clustered at the area level, in brackets.
* p<.1, ** p<.05, *** p<.01

Table 7: Social effects, Endline 2
    girl515_school_2    boy515_school_2 girl515_workhrs_pc_2    boy515_workhrs_pc_2 girl1620_school_2   boy1620_school_2    women_emp_index_2   female_biz_pct_2    female_biz_new_2    social_index_2
    b/se    b/se    b/se    b/se    b/se    b/se    b/se    b/se    b/se    b/se
treatment   0.0145  0.00741 0.0916  -0.531* 0.0210  -0.0212 -0.0110 -0.0436**   -0.00470    0.00467
    ="(0.0114)" ="(0.0106)" ="(0.133)"  ="(0.269)"  ="(0.0237)" ="(0.0271)" ="(0.0205)" ="(0.0218)" ="(0.00622)"    ="(0.00948)"
r2  0.00634 0.00628 0.00124 0.00482 0.0143  0.0136  0.00553 0.00468 0.00149 0.00401
mn2 0.923   0.928   0.286   1.379   0.329   0.474   -0.00285    0.403   0.0472  -1.05e-09
sd2 0.249   0.247   3.371   8.041   0.455   0.483   0.539   0.454   0.232   0.282
N   2755    2746    2755    2746    1789    1665    6142    2644    6142    6142
pval    0.203   0.486   0.493   0.0511  0.377   0.435   0.591   0.0482  0.451   0.624
Robust standard errors, clustered at the area level, in brackets.
* p<.1, ** p<.05, *** p<.01

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might find https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-08 helpful to get familiar with the syntax for latex tables.

Comment: converting these plain text tables to tex will be a bit of work. Check if your program can't directly output tex tables, this would make things easier.